# How to select randomly a string from tuple and insert randomly on each line in a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pycharm

I have this text("prediction.txt"):

```
email01
email02
email03
email04
email05
```

I want to as classify randomly a type("SPAM", "OK") to each of the emails so that I will have something like this:

```
email01 OK
email02 SPAM
email03 OK
email04 OK
email05 SPAM
```

My code is the below:

```
import os
import random


class BaseFilter:

    def __init__(self, mail, em_type):
        with open(mail, 'r') as f:
            self.em_type = f.read().replace('\n', em_type)


class RandomFilter(BaseFilter):
    "Returns randomly either SPAM or OK"
    types = ('SPAM', 'OK')
    rand_type = random.choice(types)

    def __init__(self, mail):

        types = ('SPAM', 'OK')
        rand_type = random.choice(types)
        super().__init__(mail, em_type= ' ' + rand_type + '\n')
```

When testing it through following:

```
random = RandomFilter('prediction.txt')
print(random.em_type)
```

But what I actually receive is either this:

```
email01 SPAM
email02 SPAM
email03 SPAM
email04 SPAM
email05 SPAM
```

Or this:

```
email01 OK
email02 OK
email03 OK
email04 OK
email05 OK
```

Therefore how can i receive randomly OK or SPAM on each line?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem springs from the fact that the input `em_type` parameter of your `BaseFilter.__init__()` method has just a single value.

When you call it, after running

```
rand_type = random.choice(types)
super().__init__(mail, em_type= ' ' + rand_type + '\n')
```

the `rand_type` is *either* OK *or* SPAM. There is no room for variability. So, within `BaseFilter.__init__()` you are marking all the lines as being of type `em_type`, where `em_type` is one value.

I would suggest that you not try to do all the work in the `__init__` method. Instead, try writing a [*generator* function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) as an [*iterator*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) on your object:

```
def classify(self, text):
    """Given a text, return a classification of either 'OK' or 'SPAM'."""
    return random.choice(self.types)

def __iter__(self):
    with open(self.mailfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            text = line.strip()
            classification = self.classify(text)
            yield f"{text} {classification}"
            # py<3.6: yield "{} {}".format(text, classification)
```

Comment: I tried running the above code, all what i get is "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" therefore which parameter shall I exactly use when printing it out?

Answer (score 0):

You properly needs to use `random.SystemRandom()`. By default Python generate randoms by system time, if you run your random generation within a short period of time, it will give the same "random" result (To my knowledge, this is a common issue with random generation on OS).